# Trying to remove iframe source when element is hidden Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an iframe source when the element is hidden

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").is(":hidden",function(){
        $('iframe').attr("src","");
    });

    $("#myModal").is(":visible",function(){
            $('iframe').attr("src","http://google.com");
        });
   });
```

by default, the modal i created has a

```
style="display:none"
```

what I would like to happen is to have the iframe source empty if the modal is hidden

```
<iframe src="">
```

and load a source when the modal is visible or if

```
style="display:block;"
```

I tried several method but nothing works and came up with the one above but still doesn't work.

Comment: `.is()` simply returns `true` or `false`, it's not an *event* - you cannot attach a callback function to it. You need to determine *when* you want to check the visibility, as right now, even if your code were to be cleaned up and in a working state, it would only check *once* when the page loads. It's likely that you want to include the code to hide/show the iframe wherever you hide/show the modal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap modal, you could refer this: [Modal#Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

Then, your js code can be edited to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        $('iframe').attr("src","");
    });

    $("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal",function(){
        $('iframe').attr("src","http://google.com");
    });
});
```

To make the code clearly, you could write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var modal = $("#myModal"), iframe = $('iframe');

    var onhidden = function(){
        iframe.attr("src","");
    };

    var onshown = function(){
        iframe.attr("src","http://google.com");
    };

    modal.on("hidden.bs.modal", onhidden)
         .on("shown.bs.modal", onshown);
 });
```